# MongoDB id remains null after InsertOneAsync

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a base class Entity that has a string Id member and a derived class A.

But when creating a new instance of the derived class and using InsertOneAsync to add it to my collection, the document is added to the database with null as the Id value.

Using an ObjectId as the Id does seem to work, but I'm trying to prevent MongoDB dependency in my models.

I also experimented with the following code, but the results are the same:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Entity>(cm =>
{
    cm.MapIdField(x => x.Id).SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally got it to work (with the 2.0 driver) with these attributes:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
```

Or the equivalent BsonClassMap fluent interface:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Entity>(cm =>
{
      cm.MapIdField(x => x.Id)
      .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
      .SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
});
```

I tried to get the same working with .ReplaceOneAsync with Upsert on but that always leaves the id still null

Comment: Do you have problems retrieving the Id after you saved? I landed on the same solution as you for the original problem, but now I cannot seem to get the Id of the newly saved object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying not to use ObjectID in your model. The ID doesn't have to be an objectID. You can decorate a string field as ID.

I have used string property with `[BsonId]` attribute without any issues.

Comment: The documentation at https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#id-generators indeed indicates that if the Id is null it should automatically generate one. But even with the BsonId attribute (which shouldn't even be necessary as the name of the member is Id), this doesn't work for me. Only if I change the type to ObjectId a value is automatically generated as expected. So it might be a bug (I'm using version 2.0.0 of the MongoDB.Driver).